# C# Deleting duplicated entries and summing the values of the deleted entries to the first one

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My code is to remove the duplicated Invoices and sum some values to the main one to keep only one invoice with the same Hash instead of more with the same.

My code:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        class Program
        {
            //File
            const string FILE = "ccc.xml";
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILE);

                List <XElement> originalInvoices = doc.Descendants("Invoice").ToList();

                var groups = originalInvoices.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Hash")).ToList();

                var finalInvoices = groups.Select(x => new {
                    unit = x.Descendants("UnitPrice").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                    credit = x.Descendants("CreditAmount").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                    tax = x.Descendants("TaxPayable").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                    net = x.Descendants("NetTotal").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                    gross = x.Descendants("GrossTotal").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                    first = x.First()
                }).ToList();

                foreach (var finalInvoice in finalInvoices)
                {
                    finalInvoice.first.Element("Line").SetElementValue("UnitPrice", finalInvoice.unit);
                    finalInvoice.first.Element("Line").SetElementValue("CreditAmount", finalInvoice.credit);
                    finalInvoice.first.Element("DocumentTotals").SetElementValue("TaxPayable", finalInvoice.tax);
                    finalInvoice.first.Element("DocumentTotals").SetElementValue("NetTotal", finalInvoice.net);
                    finalInvoice.first.Element("DocumentTotals").SetElementValue("GrossTotal", finalInvoice.gross);
                }

                doc.Element("SalesInvoices").ReplaceWith(new XElement("SalesInvoices", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));
                Console.WriteLine(doc);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that my code is exploding when it reaches the following line at the end:

```
doc.Element("SalesInvoices").ReplaceWith(new XElement("SalesInvoices", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));
```

The error: 'System.NullReferenceException' but I don't know why is it null since I have invoices, but when adding breakpoints it does not find any duplicated invoices when I have them.

I can't fix it my file is this one: [Pastebin XML File](https://pastebin.com/1PCQgcDZ)

Basically, the code should delete the Invoices repeated Hash and sum the values of UnitPrice, CreditAmount, TaxPayable, NetTotal, and GrossTotal where UnitPrice and Credit must be the same as NetTotal.

So instead of having many Invoices with the same Hash, I will have only one Invoice with that hash that has the sum of the values above.

The code already removes the duplicated ones and sums the values but somehow I don't know how to fix the problem.

It would be great if someone helps me with the solution, on how to parse my entire file because at the moment it tells me that I have no invoices when I have them.

Updted my code by adding the "XNamespace n = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;":

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

    XNamespace n = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;


    List <XElement> originalInvoices = doc.Root.Descendants(n + "Invoice").ToList();

    var groups = originalInvoices.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element(n + "Hash")).ToList();

    var finalInvoices = groups.Select(x => new {
        unit = x.Descendants(n + "UnitPrice").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
        credit = x.Descendants(n + "CreditAmount").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
        tax = x.Descendants(n + "TaxPayable").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
        net = x.Descendants(n + "NetTotal").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
        gross = x.Descendants(n + "GrossTotal").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
        first = x.First()
    }).ToList();

    foreach (var finalInvoice in finalInvoices)
    {
        finalInvoice.first.Element(n + "Line").SetElementValue("UnitPrice", finalInvoice.unit);
        finalInvoice.first.Element(n + "Line").SetElementValue("CreditAmount", finalInvoice.credit);
        finalInvoice.first.Element(n + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue("TaxPayable", finalInvoice.tax);
        finalInvoice.first.Element(n + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue("NetTotal", finalInvoice.net);
        finalInvoice.first.Element(n + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue("GrossTotal", finalInvoice.gross);
    }
```

I still have the same error but now when I reach the foreach the values are not null, but still have the same error in the line `doc.Element("SalesInvoices").ReplaceWith(new XElement("SalesInvoices", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));`

Comment: We are trying to fix it for a school work it was part of the help that @jdweng give us in another answer, but now the file is bigger and has some lines above, so I don't really know how to fix it because it says that we don't have any invoices when we have.

Comment: What does "my code is exploding" mean? We can't just copy/paste your code and run it ourselves, so without knowing what the error is, we can't offer much help.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm getting the following error 'System.NullReferenceException' but I don't know why since I have invoices so why is it getting Null?

Comment: You have a lot of chained methods in that line, try breaking them out to individual pieces and see what part is failing.

Comment: From : first = x.First() To : first = x

Comment: @jdweng Sorry for my ignorance but I could not get it, what do you mean by "From : first = x.First() To : first = x"

Comment: Adding one breakpoint in this two lines:
`List <XElement> originalInvoices = doc.Root.Descendants("Invoice").ToList();

            var groups = originalInvoices.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Hash")).ToList();`
My `originalinvoices` is allways null and the count = 0

Comment: I have another problem @jdweng if you would like to help with it, I think the problem is in the last line where I write the file with the updated values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760793/when-writing-file-3-lines-are-deleted-and-should-not?noredirect=1#comment86541733_49760793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is two issues with your code
1) Namespaces are needed
2) SalaesInvoices is not an element of doc but a descendant

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        //File
        const string FILE = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILE);
            XElement AuditFile = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = AuditFile.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<XElement> originalInvoices = doc.Descendants(ns + "Invoice").ToList();

            var groups = originalInvoices.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "Hash")).ToList();

            var finalInvoices = groups.Select(x => new
            {
                unit = x.Descendants(ns + "UnitPrice").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                credit = x.Descendants(ns + "CreditAmount").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                tax = x.Descendants(ns + "TaxPayable").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                net = x.Descendants(ns + "NetTotal").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                gross = x.Descendants(ns + "GrossTotal").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                first = x.First()
            }).ToList();

            foreach (var finalInvoice in finalInvoices)
            {
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "Line").SetElementValue(ns + "UnitPrice", finalInvoice.unit);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "Line").SetElementValue(ns + "CreditAmount", finalInvoice.credit);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns + "TaxPayable", finalInvoice.tax);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns +"NetTotal", finalInvoice.net);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns + "GrossTotal", finalInvoice.gross);
            }

            doc.Descendants(ns + "SalesInvoices").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(new XElement("SalesInvoices", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));
            Console.WriteLine(doc);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! "2) SalaesInvoices is not an element of doc but a descendant" that's what I was missing when I updated my code! I was still using SalesInvoices as Element

Comment: Thanks for your answer and to help me!, Your code works too!

Comment: I still have found one thing the output is adding some weird stuff as  `xmlns=""
   xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Tax:EN_132.03_01"` in the SalesInvoices and Invoice tags like this:  `<SalesInvoices xmlns="">
    <Invoice xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Tax:EN_132.03_01">`

Comment: I think there was missing one `ns +` to look like:  `doc.Descendants(ns + "SalesInvoices").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(new XElement(ns + "SalesInvoices", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));` with that everything looks great. in my case istead of ns should be only n

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
doc.Element("SalesInvoices").ReplaceWith(new XElement("SalesInvoices", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));
```

by

```
var firstOnes = finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first);
var xElement = new XElement("SalesInvoices", firstOnes);
var salInv = doc.Element("SalesInvoices");
salInv.ReplaceWith(xElement);
```

and set a breakpoint on the first statement. Then single-step through and understand what's happening. Or just run and see what gets null where.

**By the way:** If I am not completely mistaken, "groups" is a list of IGrouping< string,XElement>, so if you - as on the next line after getting "groups" - select an x from this list, it is again an IGrouping which does not have Descendants. For the latter it would have to be an XElement, right?