# When writing file 3 lines are deleted, and should not

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am removing the duplicated entries in one XML file, and the code is removing them and summing the values to have only one entry of each invoice.
But when it reaches the end it removes 3 lines the following ones:

```
      <NumberOfEntries>11972</NumberOfEntries>
      <TotalDebit>0</TotalDebit>
      <TotalCredit>34422.86</TotalCredit>
```

So instead of having the final file like:

```
...
      <SourceDocuments>
        <SalesInvoices>
          <NumberOfEntries>11972</NumberOfEntries>
          <TotalDebit>0</TotalDebit>
          <TotalCredit>34422.86</TotalCredit>
          <Invoice>
            <InvoiceNo>FS 006120180101/19959</InvoiceNo>
...
```

It appears like:

```
...
      <SourceDocuments>
        <SalesInvoices>
          <Invoice>
            <InvoiceNo>FS 006120180101/19959</InvoiceNo>
...
```

My code is the following one:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        //Ficheiro 
        const string FILENAME = "ccc.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;



            List<XElement> originalInvoices = doc.Descendants(ns + "Invoice").ToList();

            var groups = originalInvoices.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "Hash")).ToList();

            var finalInvoices = groups.Select(x => new
            {
                unit = x.Descendants(ns + "UnitPrice").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                credit = x.Descendants(ns + "CreditAmount").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                tax = x.Descendants(ns + "TaxPayable").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                net = x.Descendants(ns + "NetTotal").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                gross = x.Descendants(ns + "GrossTotal").Sum(z => (decimal)z),
                first = x.First()
            }).ToList();

            foreach (var finalInvoice in finalInvoices)
            {
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "Line").SetElementValue(ns + "UnitPrice", finalInvoice.unit);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "Line").SetElementValue(ns + "CreditAmount", finalInvoice.credit);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns + "TaxPayable", finalInvoice.tax);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns + "NetTotal", finalInvoice.net);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns + "GrossTotal", finalInvoice.gross);
            }

            doc.Descendants(ns + "SalesInvoices").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(new XElement(ns + "SalesInvoices", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));
            doc.Descendants(ns + "SalesInvoices").
            Console.WriteLine(doc);
            doc.Save("Root.xml");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
    }
```

And you can see a sample of my XML file here: [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/NEfMzTfk)

Can someone help me with this, how can I make it to not remove those 3 lines?
The problem is probably on the last line where it writes the file, but I'm not sure.

```
doc.Descendants(ns + "SalesInvoices").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(new XElement(ns + "SalesInvoices", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));
```

**Small Update on the question:**
Well I really think that the problem is on the line above because if I change for example `SalesInvoices` with `TotalCredit` which is the last line of the ones that are disappearing the file still wrong but instead of:

```
...
      <SourceDocuments>
        <SalesInvoices>
          <Invoice>
            <InvoiceNo>FS 006120180101/19959</InvoiceNo>
...
```

I'm getting:

```
...
      <SourceDocuments>
        <SalesInvoices>
          <NumberOfEntries>11972</NumberOfEntries>
          <TotalDebit>0</TotalDebit>
          <TotalCredit>
          <Invoice>
            <InvoiceNo>FS 006120180101/19959</InvoiceNo>
...
```

there is a missing `34422.86</TotalCredit>` before tag `<Invoice>`

and it's adding the `</TotalCredit>` after the first closed element `</Invoice>` as you can test here: [Link to test the code](http://rextester.com/NJRABW9686)

Comment: I would start with using the debugger, and stepping thru the code.. your are removing them probably when you are using your ReplaceWith method.. please debug on your end first..

Comment: I did it but unfortunately, I could not find why it is removing those 3 lines.

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to fix.   Just add the missing 3 elements :

```
            foreach (var finalInvoice in finalInvoices)
            {
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "Line").SetElementValue(ns + "UnitPrice", finalInvoice.unit);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "Line").SetElementValue(ns + "CreditAmount", finalInvoice.credit);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns + "TaxPayable", finalInvoice.tax);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns + "NetTotal", finalInvoice.net);
                finalInvoice.first.Element(ns + "DocumentTotals").SetElementValue(ns + "GrossTotal", finalInvoice.gross);
            }

            XElement salesInvoices = doc.Descendants(ns + "SalesInvoices").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement numberOfEntries = salesInvoices.Element(ns + "NumberOfEntries");
            XElement totalDebit = salesInvoices.Element(ns + "TotalDebit");
            XElement totalCredit = salesInvoices.Element(ns + "TotalCredit");

            salesInvoices.ReplaceWith(new XElement(ns + "SalesInvoices", new object[] {
                numberOfEntries,
                totalDebit,
                totalCredit,
                finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)
            }));
```

Comment: I never thought I could add the missing fields! I was always thinking that the problem would be in the way I was doing the replace. Thanks for your help one more time! Would you advise me any link or book to read and get some knowledge about linq?

Comment: The issue was with the replace.  You removed the 3 elements.  the issue is really with the three elements followed by an array of elements.  You needed to replace the array while skipping the the first three items.  So you could of done something like salesInvoices.Elements().Skip(3), but I didn't like that solution.  Don't have any good references to Xml Line, but often use following for straight linq : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b